# How to have multiple users in a user reference field

Tags: 8

I'm using Drupal 8.

Can I have multiple users by comma separating each users? When I was doing by this way, after I input a comma, I can choose another user again. But after I submit it. Only the last user I have chose that had been saved (only 1 value).

If I set the field as "Allowed number of values to Unlimit or a number". There will be many user reference text box. I only want one user reference text box and have multiple users with comma separating. How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.
You need to select "Autocomplete (Tags style)" as the widget you use in the Form display.

[image]

After you have done that, you can use commas to add multiple users in the same widget (provided you have set cardinality to > 1).

[image]

Comment: It works very well for me! Thanks so much for your help!